# Timeline creation library for java

Tags: data-visualization, java, time-limiting

I need to create time lines diagram using my Java (J2SE) application.
What library can use to create a time line diagram like **ANY** of these:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[TimeFlow](http://flowingmedia.com/timeflow.html) is pretty nice, check out their [wiki](https://github.com/FlowingMedia/TimeFlow/wiki).

There's also [Jaret timebars component](http://jaret.de/timebars/documentation/timebars.html) but it seems a little outdates.

Comment: Timeflow also seems out of date. The last commit was 2 years ago, there are only 16 commits so far. Its in Alpha.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [JARET Timebars](http://jaret.de/timebars/index.html). You can try using that.